# VS code API documentation isn't clear on how to read json customizable values

Tags: json, api, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I ahve read both the online docuemntation and the source code for the VS code API and it is still not clear to me how to read the JSON user settings and workpsace settings. I ahve tried to look for examples but I can't find something that just displays how to do this.

In essence I want a value in the settings called "maximum". I want then to read the value of maximum from the TS scrypt.

The documentation has led me to write the following two lines in the activate function:

```
const config = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('extension', vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri);
vscode.window.showInformationMessage(config.has('configuration').toString());
```

In the package.json file I have added, under contributes:

```
    "configuration": {
        "maximum":
        {
            "type": ["integer"],
            "default": 40,
            "description": "The level of alignment, how far the titles will extend horizontally"
        }
    }
```

However I get false as an output.

I have tried multiple different outputs and the only time I got true was when the parameter of the first function was 'launch' and the second parameters was 'configurations'.

I do nmot understand from the documentation alone what the parameters need to be. Nor where should the value be specified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get `False` as output because the configuration keyword in the package.json indicates only the [configuration contribution](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-points#_contributesconfiguration) point of your extension.
I would suggest you to adopt the vscode example to your needs:

```json
"contributes": {
    "configuration": {
        "type": "object",
        "title": "This is my config",
        "properties": {
            "myExtensionName.maximum": {
                "type": "integer",
                "default": 40,
                "description": "The level of alignment, how far the titles will extend horizontally."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you run the following you should get returned `true`:

```ts
 const config = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('myExtensionName');
 vscode.window.showInformationMessage(config.has('maximum').toString());
```

I think you can not separately get the workspace and user settings, because vscode's pattern is that the workspace settings override the user settings.
From the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings):

> VS Code provides two different scopes for settings:
>
> - User Settings - Settings that apply globally to any instance of VS Code you open.
> - Workspace Settings - Settings stored inside your workspace and only apply when the workspace is opened.
>
> Workspace settings override user settings.